# how to slow toggle between two functions jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


function aaa(){


$('.poss img').toggle(function () {
    $(this).css({border: '2px solid white'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 2
    }, 9000);
},function () {
     $(this).animate({
        borderWidth: 2
    }, 9000);
     aaa();
     
});

}
aaa();

});
```

```css
.poss{
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 90px;
}

.poss img {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 80px;
border: 2px solid white;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px rgba(30, 38, 74, 0.86);

 -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- comt -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/stylesheets/style.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= baseUrl %>/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= baseUrl %>/javascripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="<%= baseUrl %>/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= baseUrl %>javascripts/appscript.js"></script>

    <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body background="<%= baseUrl %>images/back.jpg">

<div class="poss" style=" float: none; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; "  >
                      
                    </div>   
                        
                        
</body>

</html>
```

Here I attach html, css, and j query.
Here I look for slowing down the simultaneously shifting between two functions in jquery. The `<div>` images should start animating after page load without any events to trigger. I also want to insert a delay on the toggle.

Comment: some one please find answer for this code please..

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/jQuery/Toggleamongtwoormorefunctioncallseveryotherclick.htm chekc this

Comment: how can i insert a delay on this toggle . I  want this two functions to be simultaniously executing one after the other.

Comment: What you've tried so far ? Show us your code to understand what you're doing, for god say

Comment: In the above attached jquery I want the two functions to be simultaniously executed.

Comment: how can i insert delay while toggling betwen two functions..??. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `setTimeout(function, milliseconds)` "timing events" provided by javascript.

The first parameter is a function to be executed.

The second parameter indicates the number of milliseconds before execution.

Example:

```
$('.poss img').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css({
        border: '2px solid white'
    }).animate({
        borderWidth: 2
    }, 9000);
}, setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        borderWidth: 2
    }, 9000);
}, 3000));
```